# jQuery Delay Question

Tags: jquery, delay

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".module .caption").hide();
  $(".module").hover(function() {
     $(this).find(".caption").slideDown().end().siblings('.module').addClass('under');
   },function() {
     $(this).find(".caption").slideUp().end().siblings('.module').removeClass('under').delay(10000);   
   });
 });
</script>
```

This works great, except the .delay doesn't work, is my syntax wrong? I'm just trying to accomplish haveing the .removeClass("under") delayed by a second or two when the mouse un-hovers. I don't want to delay the slideUp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delay()` works on the `fx` queue by default. `removeClass` does not get added to any queues, so cannot be affected by `delay()` without some changes.

You can either:

1. Add the `removeClass` call to the `fx` queue manually
2. Use `setTimeout` instead.

Solution 1 **Note the reshuffling of `delay` in the jQuery chain as well!**:

```
$(this).find(".caption").slideUp().end().siblings('.module').delay(1000).queue(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('under').dequeue(); // dequeue is IMPORTANT!
});
```

Solution 2:

```
  $(".module").hover(function() {
     $(this).find(".caption").slideDown().end().siblings('.module').addClass('under');
   },function() {
     var self = $(this).find(".caption").slideUp().end().siblings('.module');

     setTimeout(function () {
        self.removeClass('under');
     }, 1000);   
   });
```

Note that both solutions will give weird (but different) effects if someone mouse overs/ outs a few times. To solve the issues with #1, add `.stop().clearQueue()` to the chain on mouse over. To solve #2, store a reference to the timeout, and `clearTimeout(theVariable)` on mouse over.

Comment: You should also clear that timer in the `mouseenter` (mot mouseover! it's different :) function, I recommend storing the int representing it in `.data()`